# Perl print $(^b)

Tags: perl

When I found Perl's `$^O`, I was curious whether there are more variables like this, because `^` reminded me of a regular expression. When I enter

```
print "$(^b)";
```

it comes up with some numbers:

```
1000 81 90 91 92 93 100 150 1000
```

What to these mean? Is this some kind of `0xdeadbeef`?

Comment: You should be getting the `^b)` at the end.  I got '`20 20 103 101 12 61 204 401 102^b)`'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are just printing out the value of [$(](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

> The real gid of this process. If you are on a machine that supports membership in multiple groups simultaneously, gives a space separated list of groups you are in. The first number is the one returned by getgid() , and the subsequent ones by getgroups() , one of which may be the same as the first number.
>
> However, a value assigned to $( must be a single number used to set the real gid. So the value given by $( should not be assigned back to $( without being forced numeric, such as by adding zero. Note that this is different to the effective gid ($) ) which does take a list.
>
> You can change both the real gid and the effective gid at the same time by using POSIX::setgid() . Changes to $( require a check to $! to detect any possible errors after an attempted change.

Here is the comparison:

```
diff <(perl -le 'print "$(";') <(perl -le 'print "$(^b)";')
1c1
< 20 20 402 12 33 61 79 80 81 98 100 204 401
---
> 20 20 402 12 33 61 79 80 81 98 100 204 401^b)
```

Comment: oh, yes they match. and also I inserted (). Otherwise you get something like STDOUT_TOP. Thank.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation on [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for a list of all the various built-in variables (along with their `use English;` equivalent names).